# Fixar primeira coluna e cabeçalho de uma tabela HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap

Olá,

Tenho este fiddle exemplificando exatamente como é a minha tabela:

O que estou tentando fazer é, além de manter a primeira coluna fixa, como está exemplificado no fiddle, onde segui um exemplo daqui da comunidade, gostaria de fixar tambem o cabeçalho, porque quando a tabela é muito grande, fica confuso de analisar os dados, ainda mais no mobile. Tentei seguir o mesmo exemplo mas sem sucesso, alguma sugestao?

obs: Estou usando bootstrap na construção da tabela.

**html**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script><div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
                <th>Col 5</th>
                <th>Col 6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
                <td>variable value $11</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.table-responsive>.fixed-column {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: #fff;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .table-responsive>.fixed-column {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

js

```
var $table = $('.table');
var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');

$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();

$fixedColumn.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
    $(this).height($table.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').height());
});
```

Segue fiddle para manipulação tbm!

**VEJA O FIDDLE [aqui](https://jsbin.com/hutifufisa/edit?html,css,js,output)**

Grato!

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma é colocando `display: block` no `tbody` e depois manualmente ajustando a `width` das `td`s.

Comment: Fiz uma coisa que deu até certo, mas é estranha ao bom código. Veja isso  http://kithomepage.com/sos/Fixar-primeira-coluna.htm

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer fixar a primeira linha onde fica os table header, e seria mais interessante o código aqui na pergunta

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo realmente o seu deu certo, mas a primeira coluna não está mais fixa, preciso das duas ;/

Comment: o código está na pergunta @LeonFreire, clique no fiddle

Comment: @jvbarsou Sim, eu sei. E eu fiz minha sugestão.

Comment: @jvbarsou uma boa prática e recomendado pela comunidade é colocar o código na pergunta, nos ajuda e te ajuda :)

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno Obrigado pela dica Lennon! Peguei o costume de colocar codigo em fiddle pois sempre que colocava na pergunta, pediam para disponibilizar o fiddle por ser de mais facil manipulacao! Acabei de arrumar!

Comment: O Stack Overflow não é um fórum.

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é o Bootstrap! O CSS dele dificulta as coisa nesse caso específico. Você tem duas opções:

**Primeira opção**
Você pode remover o Bootstrap e formatar sua tabela sozinho, ai você poderá defina a posição dos *th* como *sticky*.

> Com ele é possível criarmos elementos que se comportam ora como
> *position:fixed*, ora como *position:relative* dependendo de um valor de
> offset definido.
> Para usar a *position:sticky* é preciso, além de setar um elemento como
> *sticky*, usar a propriedade *top*. É a propriedade *top* que define a
> partir de onde o nosso elemento vai se comportar como *position:fixed*.
> [Veja aqui](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/05/28/css-position-sticky)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr > td{
background: #dfdfdf;
padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}

table > thead > tr > th {
  background: darkblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  min-width: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Idade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>João</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maria</td>
      <td>43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mágna</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Luiz</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tadeu</td>
      <td>51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Edson.</td>
      <td>72</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marlove.</td>
      <td>49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emilly!</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Josefa</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Isis</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marta</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>44</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Segunda opção**
A segunda opção é continuar usando o Bootstrap e envolver sua tabela em uma div, assim você pode se referenciar por ela sem precisar "brigar" com o CSS do Bootstrap. O problema dessa abordagem é que você precisa definir uma altura para a tabela.

```css
.table_fixed_box{
  overflow: auto; 
  max-height: 70vh;
}

.table_fixed_box thead th {
  position: sticky !important; 
  top: 0 !important; 
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <div class="table_fixed_box">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
          <th>Col 5</th>
          <th>Col 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
          <td>variable value $11</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
table{
    position: relative;
}
thead > tr > th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

basta usar esse codigo no css

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).